# How to check if a font file is Opentype or Truetype using python? (OS Independent)

Tags: python, fonts, truetype, opentype

How would I detect whether font files are Opentype or Truetype using python?

(I am unpacking .otc and .ttc font collection files, and would like to assign the correct extension to each font)

Comment: What criteria for distinguishing OpenType from TrueType are you assuming?

Comment: The attribute listed in the details window as opposed to the filename.

Comment: Let me try again: You say that the files sometimes have the incorrect extension. What extension(s) do you expect for TrueType font files, and what for OpenType font files?

Comment: .ttf for TrueType, and .otf for OpenType

Comment: And what, in your estimation, is expected for a ttf file that should not be found in an .otf file, or vice versa?

Comment: Both ttf and otf files are OpenType fonts, the extension is different purely for historical reason, and only the font's _data_ tells a font engine what flavour of font it is (i.e. how it organizes glyph outline data and which vector graphics language it uses), not its extension. So: what are you _actually_ trying to do? What problem are you trying to solve that you think requires knowing whether a font's extension "matches" its internal table layout?

Comment: There is a script that I use to unpack .otc/.ttc files, but it unpacks all of the fonts to .ttf, regardless of their internal layout. I am attemtping to add a section that changes the fonts' extension to match their internal table layout.

Comment: If that's the issue, then it really doesn't matter what extension they have, unless you need to preserve the exact filename. But if that's the case, then your process should be retaining the original filename. One might distinguish .otf files by virtue of have a 'CFF ' or 'CFF2' table rather than a 'glyf' table, but that's not a required or consistent correlation.

Comment: The script requires me to set a file extension for the fonts it unpacks, and I do not know how to set a file extension that matches the internal type of the file, so all fonts are unpacked to .ttf, so I am trying to either set the file extension as the extension typical of the font type during the unpacking, or change it after.